# PhpStorm HTML5 snippet

Tags: phpstorm, code-snippets

This is actually not a question. I just need the default snippet from PhpStorm when you create a new empty .php file and just write

```
! + Tab
```

It will spit out the HTML5 basic template. Something like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
.....
```

So the answer to this "question" would be simply that code.
If someone who has a PhpStorm could just paste that code here it would be nice.

Comment: What for? It's a standard Live Template. If you have deleted it or screw it up some other way -- just try restoring/resetting to defaults...

Comment: I don't have PHPStorm and that's why I need it. I want to have that snippet in Sublime Text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got it from my friend:

This is the result of the snippet:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

And this is the example for creating it in Sublime Text 3:

```
<snippet>
<content>
<![CDATA[
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>$1</title>
</head>
<body>

$2

</body>
</html>
]]></content>
<tabTrigger>!</tabTrigger>
</snippet>
```

Just copy that code under Tools/Developer/New Snippet